# MongoDB geoNear with Distinct and Sorted values

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

My collection has the fields like below, storing user checkins(geo coordinates)

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5333c3063b15ea390b3c986a"),
    "userID" : "5332cad33b15eaaf643c986a",       
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-03-27T06:19:50.129Z"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    76.980286,
                    10.934041
            ]
    }
  }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53353a0d3b15ea063a3c986a"),
    "userID" : "533268983b15ea9f5a3c986c",        
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-03-28T08:59:57.907Z"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    76.980019,
                    10.934072
            ]
    }
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53353a5d3b15eacc393c986c"),
    "userID" : "533268983b15ea9f5a3c986c",        
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-03-28T09:01:17.479Z"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    76.980057,
                    10.933996
            ]
    }
}
```

I am using geoNear to calculate distance.
The result should be the latest user checkins(geo coordinates) i.e. sort based on **timestamp** to get latest checkin and to distinct based on **userID**

I am trying the below code, but its not helping

```js
db.runCommand( 
    { 
        "geoNear" : "locations", 
        "near" : [76.980286, 10.934041 ], 
        "num" : 100, 
        "spherical" : true,  
        "maxDistance" :1000, 
        "query" : {
            "distinct" : { "userID" : true } ,
            "sort" : { "timestamp" : -1 }
        } 
    } 
)
```

Tell me where i am wrong !

Comment: Is there not a **error** that is giving you some indication?

Comment: No error, But the result is empty. If you try to remove the **query** option. Then the result shows with repeated userID(s). Thanks

Comment: Well probably true for a `runCommand` form. But **distinct** and **sort** are not valid query terms. Perhaps you meant `uniqueDocs` and the point of "GeoNear" is to return the "nearest" so "sort" is not really valid here. Your query object fails to be a query. See the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/)

Comment: Thanks Neil. Let me go through the documentation you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this again, what you *seem* to want is the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) form, which has been available since the 2.4 release:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear":  {
          "near" : [76.980286, 10.934041 ], 
          "num" : 100, 
          "spherical" : true,  
          "maxDistance" :1000,
          "distanceField": "calculated"
     }},
     { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1, "calculated": 1 } },
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$userID",
         "loc": { "$first": "$loc" },
         "calculated": { "$first": "$calculated" }
     }},
])
```

So what this does is uses the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) operator in aggregation in order to to "project" a "distanceField" here based on the "geo index". Then you actually seem to want to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) these results, but the *logical* thing to do is "sort" by "timestamp" to get the latest value and then by "calculated distance" as the "nearest".

The final part of your operation is you want the "distinct" `userID` values. So you use [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) here to get the results, which **after** using sort then should be the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) items found on the grouping boundary.

So that **should** give you the "distinct" users who are "closest" to a given location based on the "latest" `timestamp` value.

Which I **think** is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Neil. But aggregation uses more memory than command geoNear so I have modified the schema bit. Thanks once again.