# MongoDB geoNear on Group Results/ Distinct field of Latest records

Tags: typescript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial, mongodb-geospatial

Following are the fields with some sample data of my collection for geolocation of all the users on every 30 seconds.

**Data Collection Documents**

```
[{
  "_id": id1,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User1,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.11892896428128, 22.31833064059432]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:08:15.049Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:08:15.049Z")
},
{
  "_id": id2,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User1,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.09304942391326, 22.321831847174654]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:09:43.828Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:09:43.828Z")
},
{
  "_id": id3,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User2,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.14348330367717, 22.280082608116277]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:12:30.670Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:12:30.670Z")
},
{
  "_id": id4,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User2,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.1542041657593, 22.27487612032671]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z")
}
]
```

As per the above data there are 2 users with 2 locations with different timinigs(Old, New)
Now, I am trying to fetch the records which are near to specific point with users latest locations(New) and ignore the old or previous records of the same users. Here is the query which I am using.
Please Check `Data Query` Section

Now it is returning the following 2 objects. Please check the `Current Result` Section

But the result should be like following. Please check the `Expected Result` Section

Now following is the distance of each location from the DB Origin Coordinates
**Distance Data**

```
id1 - 3123
id2 - 5864
id3 - 3528
id4 - 2267
```

But as per the current result, Query is fetching the result of id1 for the User1 because it matches the maxDistance option of geoNear but the result should be fetched of id2 as it is the latest result. It is showing fine for User2 because both the location satisfies the maxDistance and latest result is being retrieved.

I have already checked the related questions for this almost similar issue but the issue was not checked with the same query. I am attaching related question as well.

[MongoDB geoNear with Distinct and Sorted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727589/mongodb-geonear-with-distinct-and-sorted-values/22728403#22728403)

Can anyone guide me what should be the solution in this case? I hope my question is quite clear for this issue.

Thanks in advance and Any help is really appreciated.

**Data Query**

```
DBModel.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [73.1528821581882, 22.29557552397352] },
          key: "geoLocation",
          distanceField: "distanceCalculated",
          minDistance: 0,
          maxDistance: 3000,
          query: { purpose: "tracking" },
          spherical: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          user: 1,
          createdAt: -1,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$user",
          geoLocation: {
            $first: "$geoLocation",
          },
          createdAt: {
            $first: "$createdAt",
          },
        },
      },
    ])
```

**(Current Result)**

```
[{
  "_id": id1,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User1,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.11892896428128, 22.31833064059432]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:08:15.049Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:08:15.049Z"),
  "distanceCalculated": 3123 
},
{
  "_id": id4,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User2,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.1542041657593, 22.27487612032671]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z"),
  "distanceCalculated": 2267 
}
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
{
  "_id": id4,
  "purpose": "tracking",
  "user": User2,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [73.1542041657593, 22.27487612032671]
  },
  "createdAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-08T10:13:10.224Z"),
  "distanceCalculated": 2267 
}
]
```

Comment: If you want to get such a response you need to remove the or increase your `maxDistance` as `_id:2` is not inside the limit you used...

Comment: If I change `maxDistance` to 7000, I get your expected results

Comment: @nimrodserok, Yes I am aware that it is outside the limit, Hence That's the certain condition which is must in my case and current sample data is just an example to get the output. But query must be 5000 meters and recent location. Is there anyway to match both the requirement without removing / increasing?

Comment: Of course you can get both, but your result will not be your expected results. it will be `id4` only. Not `"_id": id2` as this is not matching the conditions...

Comment: That's the issue. I want latest locations of each user and from that result remove maxDistance condition not matching results. Is there any other way to get that expected result?

Comment: There are 3 options that I understand: A. Only get users that their latest document is in range (only user 2 in this case) B. For each user get the latest document that is in range limit (even if there are newer documents that are not in range). C. Get the latest for each user if it is not in range limit (this is your current expected results)...Is one of them what you want?

Comment: Yes I want A. Only User2 must be returned as it's latest location/docuent is in the range of query. User1's latest location is out of range.

Comment: So you need to update your Expected Result

Comment: Updated the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only the users that their latest location is in a specific range from a point, you have several ways of doing it, which you can choose from according to your data.
Ideally, you would group by user and keep only the latest and then run `$geonear` for this users, but this can't be done, as `$geonear` can only be the first step of the aggregation. Two other options are:

1. Run `$geonear` without the `maxDistance` limit, but keep the distance on the document, then group and keep only users where their last location document is according to the limit. This will work on a small data set, or if most of your documents are in range anyway, but for a large data set, where only a small portion of the documents are in range you can do:
2. Run `$geonear` with the `maxDistance` limit, so you'll keep only a small portion of your documents. Then group by user and keep only the latest (from the documents in range). Next use `$lookup` with pipeline to find for each user in range if they have another, more updated, document that should filter them out.

In both cases you should probably use the `query` part of `$geonear` to filter only documents with relevant `updatedAt`, for example, last 24 hours...

The second option will look like:

```
DBModel.aggregate([
  {$geoNear: {
      near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [73.1528821581882, 22.29557552397352] },
      key: "geoLocation",
      distanceField: "distanceCalculated",
      maxDistance: range,
      query: { purpose: "tracking", updatedAt: {$gt: ISODate("2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z")}},
          spherical: true,
  }},
  {$sort: {user: 1, createdAt: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$user", data: {$first: '$$ROOT'}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: 'userLocations',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'user',
      pipeline: [{$sort: {updatedAt: -1}}, {$limit: 1},{$project: {_id: 1}}],
          as: 'newest'
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$data._id', {$first: '$newest._id'}]}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$data'}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This might be what I am looking for. I understand your answer and that was my understanding about `$geonear` must be used in stage 1. I will try to implement the same and if it works I will accept this as an answer.